# Swift ios viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear image control size different

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

i have noticed that an UiImageView that's set to take full width is not given its correct width before viewDidAppear.

This is a bit problmatic for me because:

- I load in a custom logo graphic that can have any high/width
- This means that to keep scale (and full width) I set a height constraint to match width/height proportions in the .png file

However, I can not get true image width before *viewDidAppear* - nor viewWillAppear

Am I missing a stage / tehcnique here (new to xcode/ios/swift) or will I have o maybe make my own calcluations and no rely on retrieving the width of an uiimageview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keep in mind that `viewDidLoad` is called only when your view is loaded and not yet put on a superview, so you still don't know how is it's final frame, it has just the frame you defined in its xib file (if any)

but then you add it in a superview (in many way) and so  (following its autoresizingMask) its frame size changes, and you can get them only in 
`viewDidAppear` method

Comment: That's usually not what you want though, as the `viewDidAppear` method is only called after the transition animation has finished.

Comment: right, but in this case you have to manage by yourself the view frame before you add it to a superview (i.e. in the viewWillApper you can add something like self.view.frame = self.view.superview.bounds; / objective-c code)

Comment: So supposing I would like to make a solution that uses viewWillAppear. I currenlytt get he "frame" from uiimagelogo.frame ... but since that is not sized correctly, I can not use that. You propose I use self.view.superview.bounds? I will try that now

Comment: Seems to work - I think the code should be added to the answer, but it works in ipad simulator at least - thanks! :)